# Ошибки в описании класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Сразу даю листинг программы:

```
//Реализация класса множество
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

template <class T> struct list{
    T*    data;
    list* next;
};

template <class T> class set{
public:
    set():count(0),head(NULL),tail(NULL){}                 //Конструктор по умлочанию
    set(T *m, int i);                                      //Преобразующий конструктор
    set(set<T> &m);                                        //Копирующий конструктор
    ~set();                                                //Деструктор

    set<T> &operator=(set<T> &m);                    //Перегрузка присваивания
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, set<T> &m);   //Перегрузка потока вывода
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, set<T> &m);    //Перегрузка потока ввода

    int operator==(set<T> &m);                             //эквивалентность
    int operator!=(set<T> &m);                             //не эквивалентность

    set<T> operator&(set<T> &m);                           //пересечение
    set<T> operator+(set<T> &m);                           //объеденение
    set<T> operator-(set<T> &m);                           //разность
    set<T> operator^(set<T> &m);                           //симметрическая разность

    int operator<(set<T> &m);                              //подмножество
    int operator>(set<T> &m);                              //надмножество
    int operator<(T elem);                                 //вхождение элемента

    set<T> operator+(T elem);                              //добавление элемента (множество + элемент)
    set<T> &operator+=(T elem);                             //добавление элемента (множество + элемент)
    friend set<T> operator+(T elem, set<T> &m);            //добавление элемента (элемент + множество)

    set<T> operator-(T elem);                              //удаление элемента, при нахождении
    set<T> operator-=(T elem);                             //удаление элемента, при нахождении
    set<T> operator--(int);                                //удаление последнего элемента
    set<T> &operator--();                                  //удаление первого элемента

    operator int()const{return count;}                     //мощность

private:
    list<T>* head;                                         //Голова списка
    list<T>* tail;                                         //Хвост списка
    int count;                                             //мощность (количество элементов)
    list<T>* find(T *elem);                                //поиск элемента (адреса), при отсутствии=0
    list<T>* addh(T *elem);                                //Добавление в голову
    list<T>* addt(T *elem, list<T>* t);                    //Добавление в хвост
    void del(list<T>* elem);                               //удаление элемента по адресу
    void copy(set<T> &m);                                  //клонирование множества
    int iscontent(list<T>* p, list<T>* q, int count);      //наличие элемента в множестве(по указателю)
};

template <class T>set<T>::set(T *m, int k):count(k),head(NULL),tail(NULL){ //преобразующий конструктор
    assert(k>0);                                                           //проверяем количество элементов на входе
    head=tail=addh(&m[0]);                                                 //устанавливаем указатели в добавляемый элемент
    for(int i=1;i<k;i++){                                                  //перебираем добавляемые элементы
        if((*this).find(&m[i])){                                           //если элемент уже есть
            count--;                                                       //уменьшаем количество
        }else{                                                             //если элемента еще нет
            tail=addt(&m[i],tail);                                         //добавляем в хвост
        }
    }
}

template <class T>set<T>::set(set<T> &m):count(m.count),head(NULL),tail(NULL){ //копирующий конструктор
    (*this).copy(m);                                                           //копируем клонирующей функцией
}

template <class T>set<T>::~set(){                                              //деструктор
    list<T>* temp=head;                                                        //устанавливаем временный элемент в голову
    while(head){                                                               //пока в голове не пусто =ъ
        temp=head;                                                             //присваиваем во временный элемент голову
        del(temp);                                                             //стираем удаляющей функцией
    }
}

//Отношения

template <class T>set<T>& set<T>::operator=(set<T> &m){                        //перегрузка присваивания
    if(this!=&m){                                                              //если множества не эквивалентны
        (*this).copy(m);                                                      //клонируем
    }
    return(*this);                                                             //возвращаем "клона"
}

template <class T>int set<T>::operator==(set<T> &m){                           //равенство
    if(count!=m.count){                                                        //если размеры разные
        return 0;                                                              //то они не равны
    }
    return iscontent(head,m.head,m.count);                                     //если размеры равны, то сравниваем и возвращаем, что получилось
}

template <class T>int set<T>::operator!=(set<T> &m){                           //не равенство
    if(count!=m.count){                                                        //если размеры не равны
        return 1;                                                              //то "и ежу понятно", что они не равны
    }
    return (!iscontent(head,m.head,m.count));                                  //если равны, то проверяем на НЕ соответствие
}

//Потоки

template <class T>ostream& operator<<(ostream &out,set<T> &m){      //выводящий поток
    if(m.count){                                                    //если ненулевое количество
        list<T>* temp=m.head;                                       //записываем во временный голову
        cout<<"{";                                                  //выводим символ 
        for(int i=0;i<m.count;i++){                                 //прочесываем множество
            cout<<*(temp->data)<<" ";                               //выводим в поток текуший элемент и разделитель
            temp=temp->next;                                        //смещаемся
        }
        cout<<"} ("<<m.count<<")"<<endl;                            //выводим символ конца и размер множества
    }
    return out;                                                     //возвращаем поток
}

template <class T>istream& operator>>(istream &in,set<T> &m){       //вводящий поток
    int c=0;                                                        //количество пустое
    T temp;                                                         //создаем временную переменную
    cout<<"count= ";                                                //выводим запрос на количество
    cin>>c;                                                         //считываем количество
    for(int i=0;i<c;i++){                                           //заполняем множество
        in>>temp;                                                   //принимаем элемент
        m+=temp;                                                    //записываем в множество
    }
    return in;                                                      //возвращаем поток
}

//Сравнения

template <class T>int set<T>::operator<(set<T> &m){                 //подмножество ли?
    return iscontent(m.head,head,count);                            //если исходное входит во второе возвращаем результат
}

template <class T>int set<T>::operator<(T elem){                    //входит ли элемент
    return (int)(*this).find(&elem);                                //проверяем на наличие элемента
}

template <class T>int set<T>::operator>(set<T> &m){                 //надмножество
    return iscontent(head,m.head,m.count);                            //проверяем второе на вхождение в первое
}

//basic operations

template <class T>set<T> set<T>::operator&(set<T> &m){              //пересечение
    if (this==&m){                                                  //если равны то выводим
        return m;
    }
    set<T> t;                                                       //временное множество
    list<T>* temp=m.head;                                           //временный в голову

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){                                       //пробегаем
        if(!temp){                                                  //если пустой
            break;                                                  //обрываем цикл
        }
        if((*this).find(temp->data)){                               //Если находим входящий элемент
            if(!t.count){                                           //если временное пустое
                t.head=t.tail=addh(temp->data);                     //добавляем в голову, записывая указатели
            }else{                                                  //если не пустое
                t.tail=addt(temp->data,t.tail);                     //пишем в конец
            }
            t.count++;                                              //+1 в количество
            temp=temp->next;                                        //смещаемся
        }
    }
    return t;                                                       //возвращаем то что получилось
}

template <class T>set<T> set<T>::operator+(set<T> &m){              //Обьединение
    set<T> t;                                                       //временное множество
    if(!(count+m.count)){                                           //если множества пустые
        return t;                                                   //возвращаем пустое
    }
    if(!count){                                                     //если в исходном пусто
        return m;                                                   //вернем второе
    }
    if(!m.count){                                                   //если второе пустое
        return *this;                                               //вернем исходное
    }

    list<T>* temp=m.head;                                           //временный в голову
    t.copy(*this);                                                  //копируем исходное
    for(int i=0;i<m.count;i++){                                     //пробегаем второе
        if(!t.find(temp->data)){                                    //если не найдено в том что есть
            t.tail=addt(temp->data,t.tail);                         //добавляем
            t.count++;                                              //количество +1
        }
        temp=temp->next;                                            //смещаем
    }
    return t;                                                       //возвращаем то что получилось
}

template <class T>set<T> set<T>::operator-(set<T> &m){              //разность
    set<T> t;
    t=((*this)+m)^m;                                                //через формулу A-B=(A+B)^B
    return t;
}

template <class T>set<T> set<T>::operator^(set<T> &m){              //симметрическая разность
    set<T> t;                                                       //Временное множество
    list<T>* temp=head;                                             //временный в голову
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){                                       //пробегаем по исходному
        if(!temp){                                                  //Если исходное пустое выходим из цикла
            break;
        }
        if(!m.find(temp->data)){                                    //Если в передаваемом не найден элемент
            if(!t.count){                                           //Если временное пусто
                t.head=t.tail=addh(temp->data);                     //Добавляем элемент в голову
            }else{
                t.tail=addt(temp->data,t.tail);                     //добавляем в хвост
            }
            t.count++;                                              //увеличиваем количество на 1
        }
        temp=temp->next;                                            //сдвигаемся вперед
    }
    temp=m.head;                                                    //временный в голову передаваемого
    for(int i=0;i<m.count;i++){                                         //пробегаем передаваемое
        if(!temp){                                                  //если пустое
            break;                                                  //выходим из цикла
        }
        if(!find(temp->data)){                                      //если в исходном не найдено значение
            if(!t.count){                                           //если временное пустое
                t.head=t.tail=addh(temp->data);                     //добавляем в голову
            }else{
                t.tail=addt(temp->data,t.tail);                     //добавляем в хвост
            }
            t.count++;                                              //увеличиваем количество во временном
        }
        temp=temp->next;                                            //сдвигаемся вперед
    }
    return t;
}

template <class T>set<T> set<T>::operator+(T elem){                 //добавление элемента
    set<T> t;                                                       //временное множество
    if(!count){                                                     //если исходное пусто
        t.head=t.tail=addh(&elem);                                  //создаем элемент
        t.count=1;                                                  //размер =1
    }else{
        t.copy(*this);                                              //копируем во временное
        if(!t.find(&elem)){                                         //если элемент не найден
            t.tail=addt(&elem,t.tail);                              //добавляем в хвост
            t.count++;                                              //количество+1
        }
    }
    return t;
}

template <class T>set<T> &set<T>::operator+=(T elem){                //добавление элемента
    if(!count){                                                     //если пустое
        head=tail=addh(&elem);                                      //создаем новый элемент
        count=1;                                                    //количество =1
    }else{
        if(!(*this).find(&elem)){                                   //если в исходном не найден
            count++;                                                //количество+1
            tail=addt(&elem, tail);                                    //добавляем в хвост
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>set<T> operator+(T elem, set<T> &m){              //элемент+множество
    return m+elem;
}

template <class T>set<T> set<T>::operator-(T elem){                 //удаляем
    set<T> t=(*this);                                               //копируем исходное
    if(count){                                                      //если не пустое
        list<T>* temp=t.find(&elem);                                //ищем элемент
        if(temp){                                                   //если нашли
            t.del(temp);                                            //удаляем
        }
    }
    return t;
}

template <class T>set<T> set<T>::operator-=(T elem){                //удаление
    if(count){                                                      //если не пустое
        list<T>* temp=(*this).find(&elem);                          //ищем элемент
        if(temp){                                                   //если найден
            (*this).del(temp);                                      //удаляем
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>set<T> set<T>::operator--(int){                   //удаляем с конца
    if(count){
        del(tail);
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>set<T> &set<T>::operator--(){                     //удаляем из начала
    if(count){
        del(head);
    }
    return *this;   
}

//search

template <class T>list<T>* set<T>::find(T* elem){                   //поиск
    list<T> *temp=head;                                              //временный в голову
    while(temp){                                                    //пока кудато указывает
        if(*(temp->data)==*elem){                                   //если найдено совпадение
            return temp;                                            //возвращаем указатель
        }
        temp=temp->next;                                            //смещаемся
    }
    return NULL;
}

template <class T>int set<T>::iscontent(list<T>* h,list<T>* q, int count){ //есть ли во множестве
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){                                              //пробегаем множество
        if(!(*this).find(q->data)){                                        //если не найден
            return 0;                                                      //выходим
        }
        q=q->next;                                                         //сдвигаемся вперед
    }
    return 1;                                                              //если все нашли возвращаем 1
}

template <class T>void set<T>::copy(set<T> &m){                            //копируем                
    if(*this){                                                             //если исходное существует (очищаем)
        list<T>* temp=head;                                                //временный в голову
        while(head){                                                       //пока голова существует
            temp=head;                                                     //временный в голову
            del(temp);                                                     //удаляем временный                                            
        }
    }
    if(!m.count){                                                          //если пустое
        return;                                                            //выходим
    }
    list<T>* temp=m.head;                                                  //временный в голову
    head=tail=addh(temp->data);                                            //добавляем новый
    for(int i=1;i<m.count;i++){                                            //пробегаем по всему передаваемогу
        temp=temp->next;                                                   //смещаемся вперед
        tail=addt(temp->data,tail);                                        //вносим новый в хвост
    }
    count=m.count;                                                         //копируем размер
}

//list

template <class T>list<T>* set<T>::addh(T *elem){        //добавляем в голову
    list<T>* temp=new list<T>;                           //создаем временный элекмент
    temp->next=head;                                     //указываем следующим голову
    T *q= new T;                                         //создаем контейнер для значения
    *q=*elem;                                            //переносим указатель
    temp->data=q;                                        //внесение значения в новый элемент
    return temp;
}

template <class T>list<T>* set<T>::addt(T *elem,list<T> *t){
    list<T>* temp=new list<T>;                               //новый пкстой элемент списка
    T *q= new T;                                             //новый контейнер
    *q=*elem;                                                //перенос указателя
    temp->data=q;                                            //во временном добавляем значение
    temp->next=NULL;                                         //у временного следующий - ничто
    tail->next=temp;                                         //хвост следующий в новый
    return temp;                                             //возвращаем новый хвост
}

template <class T>void set<T>::del(list<T>* q){      //удаление
    if(head==q){                                     //если удаляем голову
        list<T>* temp=head;                          //временный в голову
        if(count==1){                                //если 1 элемент
            tail=head=NULL;                          //указатели в пустоту
        }else{
            head=head->next;                         //смещаем голову
        }
        delete temp->data;                           //освобождаем данные
        delete temp;                                 //освобождаем элемент
    }else{
        if(tail==q){                                 //удаляем хвост   
            list<T>* temp=tail;                      //временный в хвост
            if(count==1){                            //если 1 значение
                head=tail=NULL;                      //указатели в 0
            }else{
                list<T>* q=head;                     //указатель в голову
                while(q->next!=tail){                //ищем необходимый элемент (для нового хвоста)
                    q=q->next;                       //смещение вперед
                }
                tail=q;                              //хвост в новый хвост
                tail->next=NULL;                     //в хвосте правим указатель  
            }
            delete temp->data;                       //удаляем данные
            delete temp;                             //удаляем элемент
        }else{
            list<T>* temp=head;                      //временный в голову
            while(temp->next!=q){                    //пока не найдем предшествующий элемент
                temp=temp->next;                     //смещаемся вперед
            }
            temp->next=q->next;                      //смещаем указатель предшествующего
            delete q->data;                          //удаляем данные
            delete q;                                //удаляем искомый
        }
    }
    count--;                                         //количество -1
}

int main(){
    set<int> intm;//пустое множество
    int mas[]={1,2,3,1,5,100};
    int mas2[]={1,2,3,1};
    set<int> m(mas,6);//первое множество
    set<int> m2(mas2,4);//второе множество
    cout<<"m= "<<m;//выводим первое множество
    //cout<<"m2= "<<m2;//выводим второе множество
    //cout<<"m2<m "<<(m2<m)<<endl;//является ли множество m2 подмножеством m
    //cout<<"m2>m "<<(m2>m)<<endl;//является ли множество m2 надмножеством m
    //cout<<"0==m "<<(intm==m)<<endl;//являются ли пустое множество и множество m эквивалентными
    //cout<<"0!=m "<<(intm!=m)<<endl;//являются ли пустое множество и множество m неэквивалентными
    //cout<<"0<m "<<(intm<m)<<endl;//является ли пустое множество подмножеством m
    //cout<<"0>m "<<(intm>m)<<endl<<endl;//является ли пустое множество надмножеством m
    //intm=m;
    //cout<<intm;
    //intm-=5;
    //cout<<intm;
    //intm+=5;
    //cout<<intm;
    //intm=intm+10+20+30;
    //cout<<m-2+40-50-3+60<<endl;
    //m=m+111;
    //cout<<"A= "<<intm;
    //cout<<"B= "<<m;
    //cout<<"A&B= "<<(m&intm);//пересечение
    //cout<<"A+B= "<<(intm+m);//объединение
    //cout<<"A-B= "<<(intm-m);//разность
    //cout<<"A^B= "<<(intm^m);//симметричная разность
    //cout<<endl<<"B= "<<m;
    //int temp=m<15;
    //cout<<"B<15="<<temp<<endl;
}
```

А теперь вопросы:
Студия вылетает с ошибкой:

> set.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
> external symbol "class
> std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char=""> > & __cdecl
> operator<<(class
> std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char=""> > &,class
> set<int> &)"
> (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@AAV?$set@H@@[@Z](/users/84/zosich))

причем просто при разкомментировании вывода потока
чувствую что косяк либо в потоке либо где-то еще, еще есть предположение что в описании =

Comment: Не хватило вопроса, продолжу тут)) желательно не готовое решение а именно указания на ошибку, можно подробно.
<br>
Есть предположение в косячности конструктора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс "set" уже есть в std, может быть из-за этого ошибка. Попробуйте назвать Ваш класс set123 например.

Comment: Лучше убрать `using namespace std;` и везде писать явно пространства имен. Т.е. не `cout`, а `std::cout`...

Comment: Если это относится только к std, то да, наверное.